# React component how to add state

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm using the following to create a tag component:

`/components/Tag/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './Tag.scss';

export const Tag = ({ color, ghost, size, label, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="tag-primary"
      {...props}
    >
      {label}
    </div>
  );
};

Tag.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onClick: PropTypes.func
};

Tag.defaultProps = {
  color: 'teal',
  size: 'medium',
  onClick: undefined,
};
```

How can I add a state to my component?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Thanks, is this the proper way to build a component? (compared to a class component) @jonrsharpe

Comment: What do you mean *"proper"*? React supports both function and class components, it's up to you what you use.

Comment: Let's say I build an atom component, like a toggle (which has On/Off state)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"atom component"*? Class and function components are both supported and entirely interoperable, write *whichever you like*.

Comment: I understand, thank you @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component will look like this:

```html
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './Tag.scss';

export const Tag = ({ color, ghost, size, label, ...props }) => {
const [state, setState] = useState(false)

// const changeState = () => setState(prev => !prev)

  return (
    <div
      className="tag-primary"
      {...props}
    >
      {label}
    </div>
  );
};

Tag.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onClick: PropTypes.func
};

Tag.defaultProps = {
  color: 'teal',
  size: 'medium',
  onClick: undefined,
};
```

Function changeState when called, it will change the state to the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Import useState hook

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
```

Then in your component initialize the state..

```
const [value,setValue]=useState(' ')
```

Comment: Thanks, is this the proper way to build a component? (compared to a class component) @sgrmhdk

Comment: Let's say I build an atom component, like a toggle (which has On/Off state)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a class component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


class ComponentName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {


    };
  }



  render() {
    return (

    );
  }
}

ComponentName.propTypes = {};

export default ComponentName;
```